# Use php to detect the string position of the last alpha character in a string?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have the strings..

```
UA30230983A012
FK903980232P00
```

How do I get the strpos of the A, and the P? I'm trying to insert a - before the last alpha character and it's not going so well.

I've tried the following...

```
$var = strrpos($var, '/^[A-Z]+$/i', 0);
```

...but it always returns false?

Comment: `strrpos()` doesn't do a regular expression search, why would you expect that to work?

Comment: Okay, then how would you do it?

Comment: You can try to to use a regular expression, but you can do it without. For instance: `$pos = strlen(rtrim($str,'1234567890'))` Assuming there are only letters and numbers in your string.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/0fy5Au

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$strings =
[
    'UA30230983A012',
    'FK903980232P00'
];

$hyphened = array_map(function($v) {
    return preg_replace('/([A-Z]{1}[0-9]+)$/', '-$1', $v);
}, $strings);

var_export($hyphened);
```

Output:

```
array (
0 => 'UA30230983-A012',
1 => 'FK903980232-P00',
)
```

Comment: Isn't `{1}` sort of redundant? Also, you can shorten the `[0-9]` to `\d`

Comment: @ctwheels, it matches the last alpha character (1 of them) followed by digits anchored to the end of the string.  And that match is replaced by itself prefixed with the hyphen.

Comment: I know how it works, I'm telling you that `{1}` is redundant and `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d` to make it shorter: `([A-Z]\d+)$` is identical to `([A-Z]{1}[0-9]+)$`

Comment: @ctwheels, yes you could do it like that.  Probably keep it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the position of a match you can get it using the function `preg_match` with the flag `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` that returns the position in the match parameter:

```
$subjects = ['UA30230983A012', 'FK903980232P00'];

foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    if ( preg_match('~.*\K[A-Z]~', $subject, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) )
        echo $match[0][1], PHP_EOL;
}
```

The pattern uses the greediness of `.*` to obtain the last letter of the string. 
The `\K` is an easy way to start the match result where you want in the pattern.

---

To insert an hyphen before the last letter:

```
$result = preg_filter('~.*\K(?=[A-Z])~', '-', $subjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace()` to match an alpha character that isn't followed by any other alpha characters.

```
$var = preg_replace('/[a-z][^a-z]*$/i', 'a$0', $var);
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/Uyina1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp to find the latest non-numeric character in the string but this might not be very easy to read a while later when you or another developer in your team comes back on this code and tries to remember what it does. What about doing it in simple and readable basic PHP code ?

```
<?php
$string = 'FK903980232P00';
$split  = str_split($string);

$last_alpha_index = null;
foreach($split as $key => $char) {
    if (is_numeric($char))
        continue;
    $last_alpha_index = $key;
}

array_splice($split, $last_alpha_index, 0, '-');
echo implode('', $split);
```

Output:

```
FK903980232-P00
```

Going backwards through the string until we hit a non-digit:

```
$add_hyphen = function($str) {
    foreach(str_split(strrev($str)) as $k => $v)
        if(!is_numeric($v))
            return substr_replace($str, '-', -($k+1), 0);
};
echo $add_hyphen('UA30230983A012');
```

Output:

```
UA30230983-A012
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$strA ="UA30230983A012";
echo substr_replace($strA,'aA', strrpos($strA, 'A'), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As KIKO Software suggests in the OP's comments:

```
<?php
$strings =
[
    'UA30230983A012',
    'FK903980232P00'
];

$hyphened = array_map(function($v) {
    $pos = strlen(rtrim($v,'1234567890'));
    return substr_replace($v, '-', $pos-1, 0);
}, $strings);

var_export($hyphened);
```

Output:

```
array (
0 => 'UA30230983-A012',
1 => 'FK903980232-P00',
)
```